# How can I delay my animate.css effect?

Tags: html, css

I have put an animate.css (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) effect on my section two title text and hr element (line). However, the effect on these elements activates when the page loads on my section one which is known as `#part1`. When the user goes to my section 2 which is known as `#part2` I want the effect then to take place. Not to sure how to make this type of "delay" happen.

**HTML**

```
      <!-- SECTION2 -->
      <section id="part2">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                  <h2 class="slideInRight animated" id="title4">about</h2>
                  <hr class="line2 slideInRight animated">
                  <div class="row">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

[Site code](https://jsfiddle.net/qg7jbxs2/7/)

Comment: Use some JS, add `active` class to part2 whenever someone clicks on it. Then with css you would do animations by `part2.active` class

Comment: Try using wow.js which has the animate.css as dependency. It triggers the animation on "active" section. give that a try

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
`.chevron-row.bounceInDown.animated {
    transition: all 20s ease-in-out 3s;
}`
in your css i thins it's working .